# Change owner of subView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm trying to implement an animation where the image of a `UITableViewCell` expands to fill up the complete view. I've the basics down, but the image is stuck behind the `navigationBar`. How can I change the `UIImageView` to make it a `subView` of the current view?

This is the animation I currently have:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *imageView = [cell viewWithTag:1];
UIView *cellView = [cell viewWithTag:2];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^(void)
                     {

                         imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
                         [cellView bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
                         [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -64, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+64)];
                     }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
                     {
                         if(finished)
                         {
                             [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];
                         }
                     }];
```

Comment: Just call `[someOtherView addSubview:imageView];`. That will remove it from its current parent view and add it to whatever 'someOtherView` you choose.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be that the table extends under the top bars.

Select your table view controller in storyboard and in the attribute inspector deselect the Extend Edges under top bars attribute.

This will restrict the top of the table to under the navigation bar.

If you want it to be in front of the navigation bar you could hide the navigation bar and the image will then be seen.